# This does not let the app post to Facebook php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a Facebook app through php. I am using the following code for users to add the app:

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '532241193565136';
$config['secret'] = '19de17575ad3d245c8cc32f5b623e310';
$config['cookie'] = true;
$config['fileUpload'] = true; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

$user = $fb->getUser();
$loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'scope'         => 'publish_actions'
    )
);
```

This should allow users to post to Facebook through the app. The problem I'm having is the Permissions popup does not allow users to select the type of Publish Permission - Public, Custom, Only Me etc. I always get `This does not let the app post to Facebook`

[image]

Posts are being added to the Facebook Page but obviously they are private to the user who added the post.

Not sure if I'm missing something here...

**Update:**

I've tried deleting the application and adding a new, did not make any difference though.

**Update 2:**

[image]

I've just tried using the application from an Admin User of the Page...`The following permissions have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app: publish_actions`

**Information Update:**

Just in case someone stumbles on this question. [Facebook's Review Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#submitforreview) states that "The review time estimate will range between 7 to 14 business days." Always important to consider these delays :)

Comment: have you tried clicking on "OK", and another pop up comes for permission related to posting on wall?

Comment: I'm only getting one popup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing nothing here. From [**v2.0**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, the permissions other than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` need to the submitted for review before you can make your app **live**; until then, only the testers/admin/developers of the app will be able to test app with those permissions.

Since you are the admin of your app, you can test the publishing but-

1. it will be visible to you or other admins/testers/developers only
2. you'll not see the provacy setting option because that does not makes sense

For the login submission (after your app is ready to be live) see [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login).

Comment: Yep, I've just seen it. I've submitted the application for review, I have no idea how long it will take. We'll probably be changing the structure of our project, I honestly wasn't aware of this change. No worries though, thanks for your help.

Comment: Just adding a comment and updating my question as well in case someone stumbles on this question. Facebook's Review Guidelines (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#submitforreview) states that "The review time estimate will range between 7 to 14 business days." Always important to consider these delays :)

Comment: @j.grima did your app got approved ?

Comment: Is it ok ,to leave app Not submitted/Not reviewed and use it on sandbox mode for the sake of laziness :)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier We ended up deleting the app, so it wasn't reviewed. As far as I know using the app in Sandbox mode will not be public...just testing mode.

Answer (score 1):

If your submission was rejected you can post using the Feed Dialog, the Requests Dialog or the Send Dialog. Your app does not need to request the `publish_actions` permission for that. It's an alternative. (see the [publish_actions permission reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-publish_actions)).

```
function publish() {
  FB.api('/<albumid>/photos', 'POST',
        {"url": 'example.com/image.jpeg',
         "caption": 'text'
        },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
             // Error trying post method - now trying a feed dialog
             FB.ui({message: text,
                    method: 'feed', 
                    link: 'example.com',
                    picture: 'example.com/image.jpeg',
                    caption: text,
                   }, function(response){
                        //successful feed dialog without publish_actions permission
                   });
          } else {
             //successful post with publish_actions permission
          }
      });
}
```